# How to find if an ajax call is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Peace And blessing be upon you :)

Basically I have two function, each performs an ajax call. Something like:

**1:**

```
function step1(){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata = {
    'URI': sendtosev
    };
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost:20012/serv1', 
       data: formdata,
       contentType: "text/html",
       success: function(result){
          $('.UID).text(result);
       }
    });
}
```

**2:**

```
function step2(){
    var stkname=$('.UID').text();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata = {
    'URI': stkname
    };
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost:20012/serv1', 
       data: formdata,
       contentType: "text/html",
       success: function(result){
          alert(result);
       }
    });
}
```

FYI: step1 ajax is performed to get some data from serv1 servlet. and step2 ajax uses step1 ajax output and through it get some new Data from serv2.

Now Currently What I'm doing is:

```
$(function({
   step1();
   step2();
});
```

Through this `step2` FormData is null because `step1` has not yet finished it's call and haven't received its output.

**Question:** How to find if `step1()` ajax is completed and have received the output So I could call `step2()`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Read through this for an explanation of async calls and how to use them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function step1(){
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata = {
'URI': sendtosev
};
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST', 
   url: 'http://localhost:20012/serv1', 
   data: formdata,
   contentType: "text/html",
   success: function(result){
      $('.UID').text(result);
      step2();
   }
});
}
//step2 implementation

//start with
step1();
```

Simply call step2 if step1 succeeded...

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery callback functions. Please see below code for reference

```
function step1(callback){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata = {
    'URI': sendtosev
    };
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost:20012/serv1', 
       data: formdata,
       contentType: "text/html",
       success: function(result){
          $('.UID).text(result);
          callback(result);
       }
    });
}

function step2(result){
    var stkname=$('.UID').text();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata = {
    'URI': stkname
    };
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost:20012/serv1', 
       data: formdata,
       contentType: "text/html",
       success: function(result){
          alert(result);
       }
    });
}

$(function({
   step1(function(result){
        step2();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for callbacks.  For example, step1 could be rewritten as follows:

```
function step1(callback){
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata = {
    'URI': sendtosev
    };
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       url: 'http://localhost:20012/serv1', 
       data: formdata,
       contentType: "text/html",
       success: function(result){
          $('.UID').text(result);
          callback();
       }
    });
}
```

And then you can code the following when you call it:

```
step1(step2);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to accomplish it

1. pass 'async:false' to $.ajax parameter. then $.ajax will not return until the response come
2. call step2() in ajax callback function